# Chatter Email customization not taking effect

Tags: email, chatter, chatter-groups

I've customized chatter emails to use our company address and logo, as well as overridden the default "from" address, which was verified.

However, none of these changes have taken effect in the email. It still shows Salesforce address and comes from the organizational email.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue - the group is a community chatter group and those emails are controlled from the community email settings. It seems that Community Chatter emails are controlled from the Manage Communities Page and that the sender is the same for ALL emails sent from the community, including the welcome and forgot password emails.